# Нет звука в ubuntu

Tags: аудио, ubuntu

У меня ноутбук emachines e732g. Я простой пользователь, без глубоких познаний. В один раз при включении из ждущего режима звук исчез, при этом на Windows7 все так же работает. Подскажите, что это может быть и как исправить этот казус, если возможно.

Answer (score 3):

Размутить (mute) всё в алсамиксере, о котором говорилось выше и поднять ползунки по максимум вверх. Смотрите скрин. ![alt text][1]Там, где внизу есть буковки, MM-канал отключен. Наводите на нужный и разMUTEваете его кнопкой с буковкой M (английской). Консоль - это терминал запускаемый в убунту.+ еще как вариант добавить себя в группу audio.  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/DvJ5m.jpg

Answer (score 2):

Попробуй настроить программой alsamixer из консоли