# pc speaker c++ beep();

Tags: c++, linux

Для *winapi* существует стандартная библиотека *windows.h* с функцией [*Beep()*](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms679277(v=vs.85).aspx).

Есть ли аналог в *gnu/linux*, или необходимо использовать сторонние библиотеки?

Comment: Эээ... Ну, такой функции нет в стандарте C++, так что сторонние библиотеки нужны в любом случае. windows.h — тоже вполне себе сторонняя библиотека.

Comment: @VladD привычка называть все то что поставляеться вместе с Visual Studio - "стандартным"

Comment: Пробовали http://www.frank-buss.de/beep/?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно использовать возможности консоли линукс. Для этого нужно залогиниться в текстовый терминал. Далее использовать управляющие последовательности (в формате для printf):

- \033[10;%d] - установить частоту.
- \033[11;%d] - установить длительность в миллисекундах.
- \a - собственно выдать сигнал установленной частоты и длительности.

Перед выдачей нового сигнала нужно подождать пока закончится текущий, иначе он будет прерван и сразу зазвучит новый.
Может потребоваться загрузить модуль ядра для поддержки pc-speaker `pcspkr` или `snd_pcsp` и с помощью `alsamixer` [включить](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/341427/130) всё, что касается speaker и beep.

Код:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

void Beep(int Hz, int msec)
{
    fprintf(stderr,"\033[10;%d]\033[11;%d]\a", Hz, msec);
    usleep(msec*1000);
}
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    Beep(494, 250);
    Beep(523, 250);
    Beep(587, 500);
    Beep(523, 250);
    Beep(494, 250);
    Beep(440, 500);
    return 0;
}
```

Запускать необходимо из текстовой консоли или перенаправить вывод stderr на неё.

Думаю в настоящее время более удобным является другой способ -- использовать одну из портируемых библиотек. Поэтому предлагаю реализацию Beep с помощью SDL в котором использовал идею алгоритма Брезенхема. Справедливости ради скажу, что для высоких частот звук консоли лучше.

```
#include <SDL.h>
#include <SDL_audio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

typedef struct {
    SDL_AudioSpec spec;
    int freq;
    int t;
    int err;
    int newfreq;
    int newt;
    Uint8 v;
} udata_t;
static udata_t uData;

static void fill_audio(void *udata, Uint8 *stream, int len)
{
    udata_t * const d= udata;
    while(len--) {
        if(!d->t) {
            if(d->newt) d->t = d->newt;
            d->freq = d->newfreq;
            d->newt = 0;
        }
        if(d->t) {
            d->t--;
            d->err += d->freq;
            if(d->err >= d->spec.freq) {
                d->err -= d->spec.freq*2;
                d->v= ~d->v;
            }
        } else if(!len) {
            SDL_PauseAudio(1);
        }
        *stream++ = d->v;
    }
}
void Beep(int Hz, int msec)
{   
    while(uData.newt) {
        usleep((uData.t*1000+uData.spec.freq-1)/uData.spec.freq*1000);
    }
    uData.newfreq= Hz*4;
    uData.newt= uData.spec.freq*msec/1000;
    if(!uData.t) SDL_PauseAudio(0);
}
void wait_audio()
{
    while(uData.newt || uData.t) {
        usleep((uData.t*1000+uData.spec.freq-1)/uData.spec.freq*1000);
    }
}
void init_audio()
{
    SDL_AudioSpec wanted;

    /* Set the audio format */
    wanted.freq = 65535;
    wanted.format = AUDIO_U8;
    wanted.channels = 1;    /* 1 = mono, 2 = stereo */
    wanted.samples = 1024;  /* Good low-latency value for callback */
    wanted.callback = fill_audio;
    wanted.userdata = &uData;

    /* Open the audio device, forcing the desired format */
    if ( SDL_OpenAudio(&wanted, &uData.spec) < 0 ) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Couldn't open audio: %s\n", SDL_GetError());
        exit(1);
    }

    uData.err= uData.spec.freq;
}
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_AUDIO);
    init_audio();
    Beep(494, 250);
    Beep(523, 250);
    Beep(587, 500);
    Beep(523, 250);
    Beep(494, 250);
    Beep(440, 500);
    wait_audio();
    return 0;
}
```

Компиляция:

```
gcc beepsdl.c `sdl2-config --cflags --libs`
```

либо `sdl-config` вместо `sdl2-config` в зависимости от версии.
Возможно потребуется поставить *libsdl2-dev*.

Answer (score 3):

Если есть `conio.h`, можно воспользоваться

```
putch('\a');
```

Про `putchar` рядом была тема, что не работает, но думаю, `putch` должен.

Comment: Мне нужна функция beep() из библиотеки windows.h . То есть мне нужен полный функционал этой функции. Прочтите о ней пожалуйста https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms679277(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: @ParanoidPanda, стоило писать это в вопросе.

Comment: Когда-то работало.